# in python I want to select faces in edit mode by the index of for loop

Tags: python, faces, select

I'm trying to understand how python works in blender  ,  I want to select faces in edit mode  by the index of for loop to modify each face separately , I tried different ways but I failed

Comment: welcome to Blender on [SE], you will get more value from a question if you follow the guidelines [How To ask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes I searched for the answer , & I was reading the blender Python online documentation , & tested the code

Comment: please read the [ask] and [tour] pages to better understand how the site works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

print(len(bm.faces))

bm.faces[0].select=True

for f in bm.faces:
    print("face")
```

With the Default Cube that prints

```
6
face
face
face
face
face
face
```

to the system console.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful , but forgive my ignorance in this field because I still beginner in Python , when I add my function to edit the faces it gives error massage , I used a function to give the area of the selected polygon then extrude it corresponding to this value  
ar = bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons[f].area

Comment: Please post a new question detailing the error message and the code you were using.